# count number of new app users a certain user invited?

Tags: facebook, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I want to award my game users a bragging story/highscore points based on the total number of new users they have added to the facebook game by sending apprequest invites.

Is there a way to keep track of the number of users a user has invited for a facebook app?

I know I could do a FQL query and count the apprequests, but the apprequests are only temporary and they do not indicate if a user actually accepted the request.

I also understand I can easily count the number of invites from the multi-friend selector callback.

The probleem I have is that I need to count the sum of all multifriend invites ever made and also only the invites that have lead to the invite sign up for the game app as new user.

or do I need to keep track of these statistics myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think facebook will give you that info via fql, you should track it via callback in some way...